# Datetime Does Not Recognize Abbreviated Months When Parsing Dates in Spanish

Tags: python, datetime, date-parsing

I'm trying to parse dates of the form `"Ago de 2022"` in Spanish in Python. For some reason, the `dateparser` module is not working on my machine, so I'm doing this manually with the `datetime` package. When using a Spanish locale, the `strptime` method seems unable to recognize dates with abbreviated months.

Here is some sample code that demonstrates the problem

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime as dt

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'esp_esp.utf-8')


format=r"%b-%Y"
dt.strptime("Sep-2022", format)
```

Returns an error: `time data 'Sep-2022' does not match format '%b-%Y'`.

Now for some other cases to provide insight. The following code runs just fine:

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime as dt

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'esp_esp.utf-8')


format=r"%B-%Y"
dt.strptime("Septiembre-2022", format)
```

So the issue is only for abbreviated months it seems. Further, the English seems to work just fine! The following code runs fine:

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime as dt

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf-8')


format=r"%b-%Y"
dt.strptime("Sep-2022", format)
```

I'm working in a Jupyter Notebook running Python 3.9.13.

Comment: That locale doesn't look right (`es_ES.utf8`?) Also, check if the locale is supported (`locale -a` in the shell to see installed locales). A quick google search finds this for Jupyter: https://github.com/jupyterlab/language-packs/tree/main/language-packs/jupyterlab-language-pack-es-ES